# how to check if value is present in a very big data record or a big list efficiently

Tags: c#, java, jakarta-ee, coding-style, contains

hi guys i have this doubt ...

if i have a record of username and password details for logging in to a website I'll most probably get the user name and password from the form and will be using to check if the given username is present in the database by using a **contains()** Boolean operation and if contains then check the password is same as saved in the database..

but for websites like g-mail and Facebook there are million of records and the authentication is very quick ...
how to they do it ..what method do they follow for this

how they check if a value is present in a large record that quickly ?
does the process involve just adding more server for processing speed ?

**ty for the answers ...**

**

- **sorry i have posted this question without knowing about indexers ..
  (just came to know that by creating indexes to one or multiple column
  the full table scan is minimized and index path is used instead which
  is less costlier   and more efficient operation ..)**

**

Comment: just now saw about indexers ...ty David

Comment: @1and0: there is absolutely no reason to apologize! So you can remove the amendment to your question (the bold text)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one SQL query:

```
select 1 from user u 
where u.login = :theEnteredLogin 
and u.hashed_password = :theHashedEnteredPassword
```

(where `:xxx` are parameters of the query).

If you have an index on the login column or even better, on [login - hashed_password], the query should not take more than a few milliseconds to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Well, they have lots of servers and high-performance databases. At a low level, the table for the hash is probably indexed by the hash for fast lookup - binary search style.

Answer (score 0):

For medium to large data sets indexing, combined with proper sizing of disk, memory and cpus, is the most adopted approach.
For very large data sets, the database can be [distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_database) and data [partitioned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29).
For very, very large data sets, aside from the above scenarios, used technologies usually involve using [map reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_Reduce) model.